# While loop in Python to notify when it reaches a certain time

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, while-loop

I don't know how to use the while loop in Python so that it will notify me if reaches a certain time.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os
now = datetime.now()
end = 1

while x == 1:
    global end
    if now.minute == *TIME*:
        end = 0

print ("Notification")
```

Comment: I don't know how to use while loop.. is very basic question...

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of what you asked:

```
import datetime, time

def delay(end_time):
  while datetime.datetime.now() < end_time:
    time.sleep(.1)  # wait .1 seconds before continuing

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) # add 60 seconds
delay(end_time)
print('done')
```

I was a little confused by what you were doing. Something to notice is the use of less than, instead of equals in the `while` loop. If you use equals it will only exit if the code is evaluated at the exact time you specified (this is very unlikely to ever happen, so you will be stuck in the loop forever). But with less than you can exit the first time it notices you have waited long enough. You could replace all of this with just `time.sleep(60)`.